# Codeigniter file download from phpmyadmin become unreadable

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-download

When i download A file from my database table (users) the file will become unreadable. The image file will become invalid and the PDF file will failed to be loaded. The size of the downloaded file also will become 1 KB.

Although at first i have successfully upload the file to the same table (users), so the file definitely is not 1kb.

[Table(users)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYvPz.png)

[Example of error when opening pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1KDG.png)

My Controller(Files.php)

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Files extends CI_Controller {
    
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user');
    }
    
    public function index(){
        $data = array();
        
        //get files from database
        $data['files'] = $this->user->getRows();
        
        //load the view
        $this->load->view('r_down', $data); //modell->view
    }
    
    public function download($id){
        if(!empty($id)){
            //load download helper
            $this->load->helper('download');
            
            //get file info from database
            $fileInfo = $this->user->getRows(array('id' => $id));
            
            //file path
            $file = 'uploads/files/'.$fileInfo['picture']; 
            //download file 
           force_download($file, '$data');//name file nk save
         //force_download($file,NULL);//name file nk save
        }
    }
```

My View(r_down.php)

```html
<?php if(!empty($files)){ foreach($files as $frow){ ?>
<div class="file-box">
    <div class="box-content">
        <h5><?php echo $frow['name']; ?></h5>
        <div class="preview">
            <embed src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/images/'.$frow['picture']; ?>"> <!-- nk view apa letak dlm %frow, ikut nama column. directory ikut folder pc?-->
        </div>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/files/download/'.$frow['id']; ?>" class="dwn">Download</a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
```

Model(file.php)

```html
function getRows($params = array()){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('status','1');
        $this->db->order_by('created','email');
        if(array_key_exists('id',$params) && !empty($params['id'])){
            $this->db->where('id',$params['id']);
            //get records
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->row_array():FALSE;
        }else{
            //set start and limit
            if(array_key_exists("start",$params) && array_key_exists("limit",$params)){
                $this->db->limit($params['limit'],$params['start']);
            }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$params) && array_key_exists("limit",$params)){
                $this->db->limit($params['limit']);
            }
            //get records
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->result_array():FALSE;
        }
        //return fetched data
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: @pradeep's answer looks correct, but to offer an explanation: `force_download($file, '$data');`- the single quotes prevent the variable `$data` from being expanded to its content. I suspect if you open the downloaded file, its entire content will be "$data". The call you have commented out, where you instead pass `NULL`, is perhaps what you really wanted, but being a relative path it's possible CodeIgniter couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `download` method should be like this :

```
public function download($id)
{
  if(!empty($id))
  {
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $fileInfo = $this->user->getRows(array('id' => $id));
    $file = FCPATH.'uploads/files/'.$fileInfo['picture']; 
    force_download($file, NULL);
  }
}
```

Your view should be like this :

```
<?php if(!empty($files)){ 
  foreach($files as $frow) { ?>
    <div class="file-box">
      <div class="box-content">
          <h5><?php echo $frow['name']; ?></h5>
          <div class="preview">
            <embed src="<?=site_url('uploads/images/'.$frow['picture']); ?>"> 
          </div>
          <a href="<?=site_url('files/download/'.$frow['id']);?>" class="dwn">Download</a>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php } } ?>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html

Comment: if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to check it as green

Comment: thank you mr pradeep, however i solve the problem just changing the  force_download($file, '$data'); to force_download($file,NULL); and it work well.

Comment: so that's my answer too, so pls chekc it as green